# Exam class: points in right margin for parts of question

Tags: margins, exam, points

I'm trying to write an exam with the same formatting as a VCAA exam. In these exams, the total number of points for the question is in brackets after the question number, but the points for each question part is in the right margin. Here is an example of what it should look like:

[image]

At this point I have got the points after the question but I cannot get the points for the parts in the right margin. I've tried using \hfill{2 marks} but this obviously doesn't put them in the margin. Here is an example of what I currently have:
[image]

This is particularly problematic when the question part is long and extends over multiple lines. Any and all suggestions welcome for this tex novice.

Comment: Have you tried \marginpar ?

Comment: Could you provide us a MWE of what you have created so far?

Comment: Can \pointsinrightmargin be turned on and off (\begingroup ... \endgroup)?

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved